# How to initialize the GraphicsDevice?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

i am trying to get a texture2d from photoChooser.
i got the photoResult.ChosenPhoto stream
i tried using texture2d.fromStream but the graphicsDevice is null.
what should i do?
fyi - i am doing this in xna-wp7 in the optionmenuScreen and want to use it later in the gamePlayScreen.
the grephicsDevice constructor is very complicated to initialize so i think there must be a simpler way.
please help!
thanks

> ```
> {
>            if (result.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
>             {                                     
>                  bmp = new BitmapImage();
>                  bmp.SetSource(result.ChosenPhoto);
> ```

```
                 photoRecieved =Texture2D.FromStream( graphicsDevice, result.ChosenPhoto);                  

            }         
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it from the Graphics class located in your game class.